# A plea for tolerance

Tags: discussion

I have generated over 10,000 reputation here, but accidentally deleted my account. Also, certain users seem to have it in for me / get a bit excited about down voting.

Can whoever routinely downvotes me be a bit more conservative with it?

Comment: yeah that's fair, thanks for letting me know :) @Nat

Comment: At this point, you should consider the possibility that the downvotes you keep getting may have something to do with the quality of your questions rather than the personal vendetta of someone against you. How about a "how can I improve this question?" meta-question next time?

Comment: i have done that @Eliran those meta questions are also on -

Comment: You sound partial to presuming you are being victimized. A good rule of thumb is [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Comment: Also see the [FAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_attribution_error).

Comment: i think persecution would a very strong word for collaboratively disliking someone @JD !

Comment: @another_stack Morning! Um, I agree, which is why I didn't use that word or one with an equivalent meaning.

Comment: i'd have thought hostility and ill treatment (victimized) pretty much is cruel and unjust (persecute). in most contexts i mean. dunno @JD i.e. doesn't ill treatment cover injustice and cruelty?

Comment: arguably (because any ill treatment leads to  suffering in some sense) ill treatment (V) is cruel (P) in which case you've said P by saying V. @JD  this is stupid -- i don't think anyone is being "cruel" or "harming" me , merely -- in my imagination -- a few unkind and unfair people

Comment: i.e. if there is a cabal of people who take gratification from down-voting me etc., then it reflects worse on them than it effects me badly

Comment: @another_stack I think my original point is that no such cabal exists. It is possible downvoting is a reflection of your posts, is it not?

Comment: why the rhetorical question @JD ?

Comment: obviously there's no "cabal" that's impossible with the site. people are so slow to reopen questions, and quick to close them. whether or not standards are set higher for some users (which people have admitted to) @JD

Comment: @another_stack The rhetorical question, from a linguistically pragmatic point, functions to suggest, but not excessively call attention to the fact that you might be conflating possiblity and probability. As this a philosophical board, it's my duty to point to said fact. No offense, meant! It is obvious, however, you are frustrated by the results of the vetting process, and es tut mir leid, as the Germans say.

Comment: i don't see the difference between a cabal and a "vetting process", sorry @JD it is not difficult to separate out a user from their questions / answers. it is the minimum we should expect from someone who is downvoting, imvho

Comment: @another_stack I respect in your right to believe there is a Deep State at work in the site to thwart your posts, and I wish you the best.

Comment: yeah thanks for that mate... be civil @JD

Answer (score 5):

There does not seem to be a particular user routinely downvoting you, since this kind of voting pattern would be automatically detected and we would get a notification.

Also, this is like the 3rd? forth? thread like this. Please stop opening ever more discussion threads about downvoting you.

Comment: no it isn't -- not really. i am bringing something new to the attention of the group. can you not see that at all?

Comment: i respect what you have learnt, but there's seems to be this typical attitude whereby any complaint gets one put in the "bad user" box, as opposed to conforming to set behaviours and being put in the "good user" box. that's fine, but especially frustrating given anonymous voting